# Странный конструктор

Tags: c#, конструктор

```
User user1 = new User { Name = "Tom", Age = 33 };
```

Почему в конструкторе используются фигурные скобки?

Интуиция мне говорит что это связано со свойствами.

Comment: вы язык изучаете без чтения руководств и книг? об этом написано в любой литературе

Comment: тот же подход используется при создании экземпляров анонимных классов а-ля `new { value = 1}`.

Answer (score 8):

Формально выражение создания объекта определяется следующей грамматикой

```
выражение-создания-объекта:
    new тип ( список аргументов ) инициализатор-объекта
    new тип инициализатор объекта
```

где инициализатор объекта в свою очередь определяется как

```
Инициализатор-объекта:
    { список-инициализаторов-элементов }
```

То есть в этом предложении

```
User user1 = new User { Name = "Tom", Age = 33 };
```

выполняются две вещи. Первое - это вызывается конструктор по умолчанию, а затем свойствам `Name` и `Age` в инициализаторе объекта присваиваются значения. Эта строка аналогична следующему коду:

```
User user1 = new User();
user1.Name = "Tom";
user1.Age = 33;
```

При этом свойства `Name` И `Age` должны быть доступны, например, объявлены с модификатором `public`.

Вы можете также использовать в этой конструкции конструктор с параметрами и вполне возможно, что конструктор также инициализирует эти свойства, но их значения в конечном итоге будут переписаны значениями в из инициализатора объекта.

Такая форма удобна при работе со структурами, когда имеется только конструктор по умолчанию, и вы можете в одном предложении вызвать этот конструктор и инициализировать поля структуры, а не писать несколько предложений с отдельными присваиваниями.

Comment: Позволил себе чуть дополнить ответ.

Answer (score 6):

В данном случае Вы инициализируете свойства Вашего объекта. В этом нет ничего странного. Если бы Вы написали параметризированный конструктор

```
User(string name, int age)
{
    Name = name;
    Age = age;    
}
```

И вызвали его при создании экземпляра класса

```
User user1 = new User("Tom", 33);
```

То результат был бы идентичным, инициализация свойств Name и Age. Но в них есть некоторые отличия. При использовании инициализатора { } и конструктора по умолчанию (Можно вызывать любой конструктор, но в большинстве случаев в этом нет необходимости) - в свойствах будут записаны те значения, которые объявлялись в инициализаторе.

```
User user1 = new User(){ Name = "Vasilii", Age = 45 };
```

Так происходит потому что значения описанные в инициализаторе присваиваются после вызова конструктора.

Или же это делается для простоты понимания Вашего кода.
Ведь согласитесь, что такой код

```
User user1 = new User { Name = "Tom", Age = 33 };
```

выглядит лучше и компактнее, чем

```
User user1 = new User();
user1.Name = "Tom";
user1.Age = 33;
```

Comment: Мне кажется, зря Вы написали про параметризованный конструктор в начале, немного вводит в заблуждение. Это вызов конструктора по умолчанию и это именно инициализация полей, как Вы написали в продолжении.

Comment: То, что вы написали, что вызов параметризованного конструктора — то же самое, что инициализация свойств, это неправда. Исправьте, пожалуйста, ваши формулировки.

Comment: @Vadim Ovchinnikov Извиняюсь, согласен с вами, был не прав. Исправил, спасибо.

Comment: @Umed Да, я был не прав, делая такую формулировку. Спасибо за внимательность и замечание в нужном месте.